# Module not found error: No module named 'nltk' on OS X 10.14

Tags: python3

I am still somewhat new to Python programming. Having read the contributions to this topic, I am still stuck:

I have Python 3.7.4 installed (with Homebrew) on OS X 10.14. 
In terms of the path everything looks fine:

```
which python3    
/usr/local/bin/python3
```

I installed nltk with pip, using:

```
sudo pip3 install nltk
```

However, when I run python Python 3.7 and enter

```
import nltk
```

it says

```
Module not found error: No module named 'nltk'
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I can't find any solutions that will work on my Mac.

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution on [this website](http://ling-blogs.bu.edu/lx390f16/2016/09/07/installing-nltk-on-mac-os-x/#targetText=Open%20Terminal%20(located%20in%20your,do%20in%20the%20same%20way.). 
All I needed to do was to install nltk without sudo, so just

```
pip3 install -U nltk
```

If anyone has wisdom to share why this might work, I'd still greatly appreciate it!

Comment: Apparently `-U` tells `pip` to upgrade packages but that doesn't seem important (https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#pip-install). The leaving out of `sudo` would install it for your user rather than the "root" user which makes it easily accessible to you but no one else. I'd guess that you have a permissions issue when installing for all users as per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36898474/how-to-install-a-module-for-all-users-with-pip-on-linux